# multiply textbox value by factor from combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox for numeric input. And a Combobox, with a list of factors 'behind' it.

I want to have the combobox multiply the value visible in the textbox by the factor chosen from the list, each time I change the combobox choice.
What  is the way to go here?

Sorry, I was not clear:
Say, the value in the TB is initially 3. Then I chose another CB item (the one that says "10") and the TB value is multiplied by 10. Then next time I chose another CB item (the one that says "100"), the **original** value of the TB box is multiplied by 100.

Comment: Get selectedValue property from comboBox, convert it to int and then use that in your calculation..?

Comment: we can improvise what you try .... present us with your attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to convert the input from the textbox to an int:

```
int i = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Maybe paste your code in? I can help you better that way